# Python for shiny, How to access input id that gernerated by iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-shiny

I am new in python for shiny.I have create text input ui from iteration that number of iteration come from user input(in example code it is 5 times).But I can not access their ID because in shiny it must call 'input.<ID>()' and deny by python input() method.Anyone can solve this.

```
from shiny import App, ui, reactive, render

def input_txt(id):
    return (
        ui.input_numeric(id=id, label=id, value=1, min=1, max=20)
    
    )

my_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_action_button("button1", "Click me", class_="btn-primary"),
    ui.hr(),
    ui.output_ui('output1'),
    ui.input_action_button("button2", "Submit", class_="btn-primary"),
)

def server(input, output, session):
    @reactive.Calc()
    def input_block():
        list = []
        for i in range(5):
            list.append(input_txt('input_'+str(i+1))) # <-- I names input ID here
        return list

    @output
    @render.ui
    @reactive.event(input.button1)
    def output1():
        txt = input_block()
        return txt

    ''' How to access input id, input value of input text ui which created by iteration
    if number of iteration is not fix with 5, but it is depend on user input ?'''

    @reactive.Effect()
    @reactive.event(input.button2)
    def get_text():
        values = []
        for i in range(5):
            values.append(input.input_1()) # <-- I am stucking here. How to access all input id
        
        print(*values)

app = App(ui=my_ui, server=server)
```

I run this in console it's ok except cannot access ID.

```
% shiny run --reload app1.py
```

Comment: The way I handle this in R for Shiny apps is to the refer to the input object b y reference with a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shiny team provided an answer:

> Use `input\['input_1'\]()` instead of `input.input_1()` and it's fine.